# Database design for a father/husband name. Use one common column or separate columns to store the name?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am designing a database for an application form an organisation uses. The form has a field called father/husband name which can have only one value. The form on paper looks like this -

```
Name : ------
DOB : ------
Father/husband name : John Doe (husband)
```

What is the correct way to store father/husband field in the database

```
Design 1:
father_name   husband_name
NULL          John Doe 

Design 2:
father_husband_name relationship
John Doe            husband
```

Comment: Both designs use two columns!

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

A table is (often) a collection of a particular type of Entity.  The "entity" here a person.  Therefore, you need a column for the person's name, leaving the relationship to be in another column.  So, Design 2.

However, what will the `SELECTs` look like?  That can also drive what the schema looks like.